# Hypothesis testing with Baysian methods: How many animals must I test to be sure that a disease isn't present?

Tags: statistics, bayesian, bayes-theorem

I colleague has come to me with a question which I have answered for him but the only statistics I have done was what I did at school and a one semester course on Bayesian methods at university, so I wanted to post the question here and see if my answer is correct.

- I have a population of $10,000$ animals.
- I want to test for a disease for which I have a test which is $100$% effective.
- If the disease is present in the population then prevalence of the disease will be $20$%.

**How many tests must I perform to be sure to $3\sigma$, and $5\sigma$ significance that the disease is *not* present?**

I suggested applying Bayes theorem, I have typed up my attempted solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/whny5/2/)

Comment: The long Bayesian interlude seems unnecessary, one can go directly to if the disease is present, then the probability of $n$ negatives in a row is $(0.8)^n$.

Comment: That's kind of obvious now you say it, I should have realised that when I got to my result! Thankyou!

Comment: You are welcome. When one has a powerful tool such as Bayesian ideas,  it is tempting to use it.